# Write a file to the filesystem then download in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to use res.download() after writing a file to the filesystem?

```
router.get('/exportjson', (req, res, next) => {
 let json = `{"@dope":[{"set":"","val":"200"}],"comment":"comment","folderType":"window"}`
 const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/export.JSON`;
 fs.writeFile('file', json, 'application/json', function(){
    res.download(file);
 })  
})
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please write a proper description of exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I'm assuming you want to be able to save that json data to the path `/upload-folder/export.json` and then allow the browser to download the file using `res.download()` at the path `GET /exportjson`.

You've got a couple of issues. First, `fs.writeFile` takes a file path as the first argument, and you are just passing the string `file`. With your code, the data would be written to the current directory as `file`. You probably want to use the `path` module and create a path to the file you want to write, like so:

```
const path = require('path');

const jsonFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../upload-folder/export.json');
```

Assuming the code is at `routes/index.js`, this path would point to the root directory of the project to the file `upload-folder/export.json`.

The data you want to write is in your variable `json`, but you have it stored as a string. I would actually leave it as an object:

```
let json = {
  "@dope": [
    { 
      "set":"",
      "val":"200"
    }
  ],
  "comment":"comment",
  "folderType":"window"
};
```

And then call `JSON.stringify` on it when you pass it to `fs.writeFile` as the second argument. You will also need to pass in the `utf-8` option as the third argument, not `application/json`:

```
fs.writeFile(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(json), 'utf-8', function(err) {
```

In the callback to `fs.writeFile`, you want to call `res.download` and pass it the path to the file that you just wrote to the filesystem, which is stored in `jsonFilePath` (you had this part right, I just changed the variable name):

```
res.download(jsonFilePath);
```

Here is the relevant portion of the router file that has code to get everything working correctly:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const jsonFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../upload-folder/export.json');

router.get('/exportjson', (req, res, next) => {

  let json = {
    "@dope": [
      { 
        "set":"",
        "val":"200"
      }
    ],
    "comment":"comment",
    "folderType":"window"
  };

  fs.writeFile(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(json), 'utf-8', function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.download(jsonFilePath);
  });  

});
```

Assuming this file lives in `/routes/index.js`, the file would be saved at `/upload-folder/export.json`.

Here is a gif showing how it looks on my machine:

[image: exportJson]

Comment: Thank you, when I go to the endpoint directly I get the download, but when I access the endpoint with an axios request, I get the json in a normal response.   axios.get('/api/exportjson', {json})

Comment: @JeremyNelson Your question doesn't ask about axios or front-end stuff. Can you post another question, or edit this one, and let me know what you're trying to accomplish? To get the browser to give you that download dialogue, you have to perform the request from the browser, not JS with fetch or axios, but you can do some work with Blob's and ObjectURL's to mock the native behavior. I have an answer where I covered it for a different use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923772/sending-an-excel-file-from-backend-to-frontend-and-download-it-at-the-frontend/58945412#58945412